# Exception in function does not return exceptions on functions in function monitor

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager, azure-eventgrid

The azure function is a .net core class library that will receive the message based on the namespace of the model being sent (in the filter as eventType) as an . All deployments are being done using arm templates, which is where this struggle is originating from. The function and eventgrid are deployed fine, but I don't know what i'm doing wrong with the subscription. If I create the subscription in the portal then the handler receives the message and displays traffic on the monitor. If I create the subscription as below then it appears exactly the same in the portal as the portal created one but nothing shows up in the monitor. Am I missing a resource or connection that still needs to be created? I read about system topics and how they're made implicitly in some instances but can be made explicitly, is that what I'm missing? This would be easier to debug if there was a place to export the template for those subscriptions but I don't see them.

**Function handler**

```
[FunctionName("FunctionName")]
    public async Task Run([EventGridTrigger]EventGridEvent eventGridEvent)
    {
        ...            
    }
}
```

**eventgrid creation**

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.EventGrid/topics",
  "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
  "name": "[variables('EventGridName')]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]"
}
```

**subscription creations**

```
{
  "name": "[concat(variables('eventSubscriptions')[copyIndex()].eventGridName, '/Microsoft.EventGrid/', variables('eventSubscriptions')[copyIndex()].name)]",
  "type": "Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/providers/eventSubscriptions",
  "apiVersion": "2020-01-01-preview",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "copy": {
    "name": "subscriptionCopy",
    "count": "[length(variables('eventSubscriptions'))]"
  },
  "properties": {
    "topic": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId,'/resourcegroups/', resourceGroup().name, '/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/', variables('eventSubscriptions')[copyIndex()].eventGridName)]",
    "destination": {
      "endpointType": "AzureFunction",
      "properties": {
        "resourceId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId,'/resourcegroups/', resourceGroup().name, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('eventSubscriptions')[copyIndex()].functionApp, '/functions/' , variables('eventSubscriptions')[copyIndex()].functionName)]",
        "maxEventsPerBatch": 1,
        "preferredBatchSizeInKilobytes": 64
      }
    },
    "filter": {
      "includedEventTypes": [
        "[variables('eventSubscriptions')[copyIndex()].eventType]"
      ]
    },
    "labels": [],
    "eventDeliverySchema": "EventGridSchema"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
  ]
}
```

Comment: are you receiving any error when creating the subscriptions ? your function app code needs ot be deployed prior to create the subscriptions as well

Comment: no errors when creating the subscriptions. I split up the creating of event grid and the subscriptions and have the deployment of the functions between them. However I think my problem is now not actually the lack of communication but rather that I'm not getting an invocation count for when it triggers even though the message comes in. There is an exception in my method in the handler which I need to fix but I though there would be some kind of response in the function monitor about it

Comment: @ian_stagib Could you help me with the function code as your ARM template is looking fine we need to check your function code to resolve the issue.